# jQuery .submit event handle not called on click

Tags: jquery, ajax, submit, handler

I'm trying to use the following to perform an ajax request when the user clicks submit on a form so that the page doesn't reload.

```
$('#pick-names-and-email').submit(function(e) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: $('#participants-summary').attr('action'),
                data: $('#participants-summary').serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                    alert('ajaxdone');
                }

            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
```

For some reason when I clicked the link on the page, it performs a regular form submit and my event handler is never called. The weird thing is if I do `$('#pick-names-and-email').submit()` in my javascript somewhere, the ajax is carried out just fine. The event handler seems to be not called only for the mouse click. Any idea?

EDIT: #pick-names-and-email is my submit button

Comment: what's your submit link ?

Comment: oh sorry. #pick-names-and-email is the submit button

Comment: you need that your **form** have an id **#pick-names-and-email**, and a submit button type in your form

Comment: oh thank you! For some reason I thought I tried that and it didn't work. Guess I had a typo before. Thanks again

Comment: Try adding "onclick" event with the button. Button don't have "submit" event but "<form>" have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **#pick-names-and-email** id was on the submit button,

the submit function is called when you click on the **submit** button on you **#pick-names-and-email** form

```
<form id="#pick-names-and-email">
    <input ..... />
    <input ..... />
    <input type="submit"..... />
</form>
```